# The 'How To Ask?' page requires update

Tags: support, help-center

How do I update the 'How To Ask?' page? (**Or** Can someone who sees this, update it?)

### From

The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page uses the original term I coined for a short example code, while writing the first drafts. To whit: **'Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example'**.

### To

Times change and that abbreviation has become **'[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)'**.

---

I'm not sure if the 'cheat tags' work in that context, but `[mre]` in a comment on SO will expand to the full text with link.

Comment: "*I'm not sure if the 'cheat tags' work in that context*" just as a side note but in case anybody didn't know about their existence (like me, until recently) - apparently they are called [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239707/complete-list-of-help-center-magic-links).

Comment: The old magic link `[mcve]` still works in that regard as well. It was changed from MCVE to MRE in late May. They'll get to it eventually.

Comment: *something* *something* [*6 to 8 weeks*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/218388)